# How to load a specific JS at the end of all other included JS files?

Tags: layout, theme

I have a specific fancybox.js file which I want to load at the end of all the JS files included in my local.xml

If load order can be changed then how can a JS file be loaded (included) at the end ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can sort the order of `skin` or `js` files in layout.xml by using the params element with a name attribute like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317044/reorder-magento-javascript-includes-addjs) explains:-

```
<action method="addJs"><!-- this will be shown second -->
    <script>prototype/javascript1.js</script>
    <params><![CDATA[name="js002_second"]]></params>
</action>
<action method="addJs"><!-- this will be shown first -->
    <script>prototype/javascript2.js</script>
    <params><![CDATA[name="js001_first"]]></params>
</action>
```

Comment: Nice...I learn something new everyday.

Comment: If i have only one JS to be included at the end of all JS files then how the above method will work ?

Comment: Try `<params><![CDATA[name="zjs_last"]]></params>` and see what happens (I'm not 100% certain). Report back if that doesn't load it after all others.

Comment: No its not working somehow..:(

Comment: @Mark - Hmm, okay, I'm guessing each js call will require a params element with name attribute or you could try [modifying so that you can include a sort order](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12614560/898933) or is it not possible to just place the fancybox js call after all others?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I don't think you can specify a sort order for the js files you add</strike> (apparently you can see answer provided by @zigojacko), but I think you can do it a bit differently, buy adding a child block to the `head` block.
All the children of the `head` block are rendered after the js and css elements.

Here is what you need.

Add this to one of your layout files.

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/template" name="fancy" as="fancy" template="fancybox/fancybox.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Then create the file `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/fancybox/fancybox.phtml` with the following content.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('js').'/fancybox.js'?>"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but here is a simple way to order your assets files using a simple custom module (tested):

create

```
app/etc/modules/Company_ReorderAssets.xml
```

and insert:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

 <config>

     <modules>

         <Company_ReorderAssets>

             <active>true</active>

             <codePool>local</codePool>

         </Company_ReorderAssets>

     </modules>

 </config>
```

create `app/code/local/Company/ReorderAssets/etc/config.xml` and insert:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

 <config>

     <modules>

         <Company_ReorderAssets>

             <version>1.0.0</version>

         </Company_ReorderAssets>

     </modules>

     <global>

         <blocks>

             <class>Company_ReorderAssets_Block</class>

             <page>

                 <rewrite>

                     <html_head>Company_ReorderAssets_Block_Page_Html_Head</html_head>

                 </rewrite>

             </page>          

         </blocks>

     </global>

 </config>
```

create `ReorderAssets/Block/Page/Html/Head.php` and insert:

```
<?php



 class Company_ReorderAssets_Block_Page_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head {



    public function addItemFirst($type, $name, $params = null, $if = null, $cond = null) {



        if ($type === 'skin_css' && empty($params)) {

            $params = 'media="all"';

        }



        $firstElement = array();

        $firstElement[$type . '/' . $name] = array(

            'type' => $type,

            'name' => $name,

            'params' => $params,

            'if' => $if,

            'cond' => $cond,

        );



        $this->_data['items'] = array_merge($firstElement, $this->_data['items']);



        return $this;



    }



    public function addItemAfter($after, $type, $name, $params = null, $if = null, $cond = null) {



        if ($type === 'skin_css' && empty($params)) {

            $params = 'media="all"';

        }



        $firstElement = array();

        $firstElement[$type . '/' . $name] = array(

            'type' => $type,

            'name' => $name,

            'params' => $params,

            'if' => $if,

            'cond' => $cond,

        );



        if (array_key_exists($after, $this->_data['items'])){



            $pos = 1;

            foreach ($this->_data['items'] as $key => $options){

                if ($key == $after) :

                    break;

                endif;

                $pos +=1;

            }



            array_splice($this->_data['items'], $pos, 0, $firstElement);



        }



        return $this;



    }
 }
```

Here we create our functions `addItemFirst` and `addItemAfter` that can be used like this (inside any layout.xml).

Example of layout.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

 <layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>

         <reference name="head">

            <action method="addItemFirst"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/jquery.js</script></action>

            <action method="addItemAfter">

                <after>skin_js/js/jquery.js</after>

                <type>skin_js</type>

                <script>custom_folder/javascript.js</script>

            </action>

            <action method="addItemAfter">

                <after>skin_js/js/jquery.js</after>

                <type>skin_js</type>

                <script>custom_folder/another_javascript.js</script>

            </action>

         </reference>

    </default>

 </layout>
```

Please note the skin_js inside your path.

Special thanks to Koncz Szabolcs.