# jQuery won't appear Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, jquery

I sit with a simple issue, but I can't seem to find any simple solutions.

I made a file in `/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/js` called `custom.js`, included this in the header, all is fine. I then paste in

`$j('<a class="medlemHeader" href="/ost-pa-abonnement-cheeseweek.html">Bliv Medlem</a>').insertAfter(".navigation-toggle");`

which appears. As I think I got success, I then wanna do a proper code, and change it to

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
    $j('<a class="medlemHeader" href="/ost-pa-abonnement- 
    cheeseweek.html">Bliv Medlem</a>').insertAfter(".navigation- 
    toggle");
});
```

This code just won't appear. It still displays the first part.

I've tried to merge js, empty all sorts of cache possible and waited some time. Can I make changes kick in immediately?

jQuery is included in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you are loading jquery after your custom js file

You can load js in a certain order

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/17874/70343

So jquery first then your custom js after